# Spring Cloud Config: Validate and Reject Configuration if invalid

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator

I am using the Spring Cloud Config Server combined with a configuration bean class with a corresponding validator class of javax.validation.Validator. 
I am able to validate the configuration receiving from the config-server at the application startup. 
The validation will be also executed when the config bean is refreshed via the actuator endpoint. 
The goal is to keep the old configuration and reject the new one on refresh if the new configuration is invalid. 
Is there anyway to customise an existing actuator endpoint to validate the config and reject it before the refresh() method is called on context ?

Following dependencies are used: 
- spring-boot-starter-actuator 2.1.1.RELEASE
- spring-boot-starter-web 2.2.1.RELEASE
- spring-cloud-starter-config 2.0.2.RELEASE

Comment: No, you probably need a custom endpoint.

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you solve it?